# Efficient way of finding max in 1d array using pthreads in C

Tags: c, arrays, linux, pthreads, max

I want to find the maximum value in 1d array using **pthreads** in C.

I have a code like this:

```
void* findmax(void* arg){
  double temp_max;
  astruct *td=(astruct *)arg;

  P[td->idx]=d*P[td->idx]+sth;
  temp_max= fabs(P[td->idx]-P_old[td->idx]);

   pthread_mutex_lock(&lockP);
    if(max<temp_max){   
       max=temp_max;
    }   
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lockP);
}

main(){
...
  //give to each thread an element of P 
  TD[i].idx;
....
  for(i=0;i<thread_number;i++){
   pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,&findmax,(void*)&TD[i]);
  }
...
  /* when the above threads are done give them new element and start the
   loop again till the end of array P */

}
```

So the problem is that the mutexes are necessary to find the correct result, but they slow the program so much that in the end **the serial code is faster than this implementation**.

Is there any efficient way of solving this problem using pthreads that is faster than the serial simple code of finding max?

Comment: Why not give each thread a large chunk of the array.  Use a stack variable (no mutex necessary) to keep track of the max each thread finds.  At the end compare each thread's local max with the global max protected by a mutex.  1 acquisition of mutex per thread per array chunk.

Comment: True thanks this is good approach. And it sounds like reducing the time. I hope it will be confirmed.................. Right now i am using a stack holding all the inactive threads because there are other things running the same time. To do what you suggest I have to use a standard number of threads. I have to change a lot of things in my code but seems promising.Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law). It limits the speed-up available via parallelization.

Answer (score 2):

Use the divide and conquer approach.

1. Start with an array `A` of length `N`. `A(i)` is the i'th element of the array `A`. `A(i,j)` is the subset of `A` that is the i'th through (j-1)'th elements.
2. Divide the number `N` by the number of cores available,`C`, on the machine. This number is `W`, the workload size
3. Define a function `maxOnSubset(i,j)` that returns a value that is the same type as the elements of `A`. The function finds the maximum value in `A(i,j)`. If `j` is greater than the length of `A`, the function sets `j` to the length of `A`.
4. Start `C` threads numbered `[0,C)`. The number associated with each thread is `c`. Each thread is responsible for calling the function `maxOnSubset(c*W,(c+1)*W)` and storing the value. You can use a semaphore to know when each thread has computed this value. This allows each thread to progress independently of any other thread.
5. Wait for each thread to complete and collect the stored values in a second array `B`. The array `B` has a length of `C`.
6. Find the maximum value in `B`. The maximum value of `B` is also the maximum value of `A`.